# designing a simple database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Suppose I have a website, and I want to add "Search a part" button, and there are two options "Dirt" or "ATV-UTV", and if for example the user choose "Dirt" to he need to choose "Beta" or "Gas" or "Honda", and if he choose "ATV-UTV" he should choose "Suzuki" or "mazda"

```
                                    [Search a part]
                                    /              \
                                   /                \
                                [Dirt]             [ATV-UTV]
                                /  |  \             /      \
                               /   |   \         [Suzuki]   [mazda]
                            [Beta][Gas] [Honda]
```

Lest's suppose that the user chose `Search a part->Dirt->honda` then I want to display the user all the available parts for this "Dirt Honda"

```
      -------------------------------------------
      |Part No| Price| Stock status| Description|
      -------------------------------------------
      | 56    | 25$  | In stock    | Repair Kit |
      -------------------------------------------
      | 21    |76$   | In stock    | Bearing Kit|
      -------------------------------------------
      | 99    | 54$  | Not In Stock| Repair Kit |
      -------------------------------------------
```

What's the best way for designing the DB for my website? I mean, how many tables should I build? Should I do 5 tables? on for "Beta" one for "Gas", one for "honda" and also for "Suzuki" and "mazda"?

Just need help on how should I design it, thank you for help

Comment: Edit your title to be specific about your particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would create between 3 tables. Of corse you could also put the descriptions in another own table but if the parts table doesn´t get really big in future I personally don´t see the benefit...

table 1: the parts
table 2: the manufacturer names
table 3: the category (Dirt or ATV-UTV)

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  |PartNo | Price| StockStatus | Description|manufacturerId|categoryId|
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 56    | 25$  | In stock    | Repair Kit |1             |1         |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 21    |76$   | In stock    | Bearing Kit|3             |1         |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 99    | 54$  | Not In Stock| Repair Kit |1             |2         |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

manufacturer table

```
      ----------------
      |id(PK) | name | 
      ----------------
      | 1     | mazda|
      ----------------
      | 2     | honda| 
      ----------------
.
.
.
```

category table

```
  ------------------
  |id(PK) | name   | 
  ------------------
  | 1     | ATV-UTV|
  ------------------
  | 2     | Dirt   | 
  ------------------
```

.
.
.

And then you can query them using JOINS

```
SELECT p.*, m.name AS Manufacturer, c.name AS category FROM parts p
LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON m.id=p.manufacturerId
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id=p.categoryID
```

Comment: I'd put the `StockStatus` in a separate table: `StockStatus` and assign the various statuses with a number.

Comment: Yeah as I said, you could normalize everything but the stockStatus I would save as a numeric / bool value anyway...

Comment: Just what I was thinking. Put an `in_stock` and `ordered` column in the `parts` table and deduce the `status` from those columns.